# How to create a well formed global javascript object containing special functions

Tags: javascript, oop

I am creating a small project that heavily relies on JavaScript. I come from php/mysql and now stepping into node.js/javascript/mongodb, and I hve to say it's quite a mindswitch.

I want to create a simple object that has some special function that I can use in the page. I have been looking at some tutorial, and looking at the libraries such as jquery and backbone, but I need some final advice on my decision.

I only need some small functions, and no cross-browser support, that's why I don't choose something like backbone. Maybe ill change to that later when I have a better crasp on JavaScript programming.

What is confusing me is whether to use the `new`, or maybe wrapping the code into a self-invoking function.

I see jquery creates an object inside the `window` and than exposes that, but I have no idea how that works.

Enough intro, now to the point. I have created something like this:

```
var $s = Object.create({

    page: Object.create({

        title: 'pagetitle',
        html: '',
        data: {},

        render: function(){
            // Basic render function
        }

    }),

    socket: Object.create({
        // My websocket connection
    }),

    store: function(key, value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    },

    retrieve: function(key) {
        var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        return value && JSON.parse(value);
    },

    slugify: function(slug){
        return slug.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9-]+/g,'').toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-');
    }

});
```

This are just a few random functions I put in.

I haven't tested this yet, it is a draft, I want to know if this is any good.

Now I was thinking i can do some stuff like this:

```
$s.page.html = 'somehtml';
$s.page.render();

// Maybe
$s.store( $s.page.title, $s.page.html );
```

I do use jQuery and jQuery templating, so something like this could be possible:

```
$.tmpl( $s.page.html, $s.page.data ).appendTo( "#content" );
```

Comment: It's hard to spot the question in your post.

Comment: I'm sorry, I want to know if it is ok to use `$s = Object.create`, or should it be wrapped inside a self-invoking function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing fancy is needed here.  You can create a global javascript object with a method like this:

```
var myGlobalObject = {};
myGlobalObject.testFunction = function() {
    // put your code here
};
```

You can then call that like this:

```
myGlobalObject.testFunction();
```

---

One slightly more flexible design pattern you will often seen used is this:

```
var myGlobalObject = myGlobalObject || {};

myGlobalObject.testFunction = function() {
    // put your code here
};
```

This is used when there might be lots of different pieces of code contributing to `myGlobalObject` and they all want to make sure that it's properly declared before adding properties to it.  This way of doing it, creates it if it doesn't already exist and if it does already exist, leaves the methods and properties on it that might already be there.  This allows multiple modules to each contribute initialization to `myGlobalObject` without regards for the order they load.

Comment: Will there be no consequenses when I Use `this` inside the functions, or putting the variables of the function.

Comment: When you call a method on an object, like calling `myGlobalObject.testFunction();`, the `this` value inside of  `testFunction` will be set to the `myGlobalObject`.  That's how javascript does it.  When calling `obj.method()`, the `this` ptr will be set to `obj` when inside of `method()`.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Actually the article that made me start wondering was the following: http://howtonode.org/prototypical-inheritance. I still don't fully unserstand it, maybe if you have the time you can clarify some of the differences in your method and the one described.

Comment: @SaifBechan - If you are just creating a single global object (often called a namespace object), there is no reason to use prototypes and inheritance - you can just declare it directly as I've shown in my example.  Prototypes are best used when you want to define a particular type of object and you will then create more than one of those objects and you want them all to have the same behavior.  In that case you define the prototype and then create each particular object instance with `new myObject()` as shown in that article.

Comment: Ah that explains the `spawn` function. That clears up a lot. In my case I just need one object. Thanks!

Comment: @SaifBechan - `spawn()` is making a new object using an existing object as a template - `spawn()` enumerates the properties and methods on an existing object and passes them to `Object.create()` to create a new object with the same properties/methods.  This is a bit unusual for regular object definitions.  There are times when it's useful, but it's usually better to define a prototype for something that you want to create more than one of and then just use `new myObject()` and let the language use it's built-in prototype capabilities to make the type of object you want.

Comment: Since these functions are not contained in a function, they cannot share variables and constants, a requirement for OOP.